# FPS drops when I add an overlay (health bar) to my camera view? (UPBGE)

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks, collections

when I run my game it plays at 30fps which is fine, but when I add a health bar overlay this drops down to 20fps for some reason. Is there any way of having an overlay in camera view without a significant performance drop? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no. UPBGE 0.3's overlay pipeline is somewhat lacking in terms of performance.

Here is youle one of the core developers explaining a partial solution earlier this year to someone else who had a similar question about his UPBGE 0.3 project:

[image]

Manually constructing your own UI with the BGL/BLF modules' would be better.
Here is the blend that youle shared in the screenshot:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/719228680374583337/903281343142703114/post_draw_callbacks.zip

Additionally, UPBGE 0.2 has better overlay performance for now, so if possible, use one of those release versions instead.

Comment: I see, is there a way to use this script to show images instead of text?

Comment: Personally I've never been able to draw images with BGL (Blender OpenGL module) on my own, although I know many have been able to, whether in BGE, UPBGE 0.2 or UPBGE 0.3. Here is one a UPBGE 0.3 UI framework though: https://github.com/mysticfall/alleycat-ui